# Again, another correct answer downvoted and a wrong answer upvoted

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The answer is this one:

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/61302/34047

Regardless of the effort I put into improving it is being downvoted, mine answer is correct (I studied metallurgy), while the other answer is wrong, clearly. Seems this problem is much more common, I see much more correct answers being downvoted with comments pointing out problems that not exist (in my case someone noted that metal are polycrystaline, which is true, but was not the problem).

Comment: Indeed, you've piqued my curiosity -- metallurgy is *not* my background at all, so I'll readily concede my understanding may well be incorrect. Is there any literature you could link to that would reinforce your argument?

Comment: Also, thanks for bringing this to meta in such a calm, reasoned fashion -- I'm sorry that this question and my answer have (I presume) upset you!

Comment: As a materials science person, I'm not sure I'd qualify either current answer as more 'correct' than the other - mainly because the original question is not well framed in that it ignores all the corner cases that seem to be the basis for your question here.

Comment: I do not like assumptions when there is no evidence provided. You need to first prove that *Seems this problem is much more common ... much more correct answers being downvoted with comments pointing out problems that not exist*. I understand your frustration but you haven't linked to any credible sources to back up your answer. Saying this as an untrained eye, but I do not see why the two answers don't align well. You speak of perfectly flat surfaces, and as that is hard to come across, hBy2Py neglected the fact that it might happen. That doesn't make his answer wrong. 'Wrong' is too strong.

Comment: which sources needed if I studied metallurgy?

Comment: Are you implying there are no good sources for metallurgy online?

Answer (score 11):

I do not have the knowledge to judge what is right or wrong with the answers and I did not downvote your post.

However, I can offer some tips to avoid such a scenario.

1. Do not whine about it either on the main site or on meta. I edited out a portion of your answer earlier. Text that simply complains about being downvoted helps you gain neither sympathy nor upvotes.
2. Give reliable references to back up what you are saying. Even Wikipedia is usually quite acceptable. On this website, this *will* make your post stand out. Right now, your answer has no links whatsoever.
3. If you believe that an existing answer is factually wrong, 1) comment on the answer stating *clearly* how it is wrong; 2) if you are providing a competing answer, put a section in the top of your post *clearly* explaining how this is so.
   I will be the first to agree with you that there is incorrect content on this website that gets upvoted. However, simply making a sweeping claim on meta ("Seems this problem is much more common") doesn't get us anywhere. **Be the change that you want to see.**
4. Write well with good English. Prior to editing there were a lot of grammar and spelling mistakes in your post. Downvotes do not always imply that post content is wrong; they are in general simply a signal that the quality of a post is not good.

Comment: Also IMHO when there is wrong content being upvoted or correct content being downvoted, it's without a reason provided. Almost always, when there is a reason in the comments, it's a good one. (Which is why the OP's assumption sounded blatantly false to me)